# Show that congruence of matrices is an equivalence relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, equivalence-relations, matrix-congruences

How would one solve a question of this nature?

We know that given an arbitrary square matrix, A, that a matrix B is said to be congruent to A if there exists a nonsingular (invertible) matrix P such that B = (P^T)AP.

Also, a matrix B is equivalent to a matrix A if B can be obtained from A by a sequence of elementary row and column operations.  Alternatively, B is equivalent to A if there exist nonsingular matrices P and Q such that B = PAQ. Just like row and column equivalence, equivalence of matrices is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Which of the requirements for an equivalence relation is causing you headaches?

Comment: B = PAQ in the second paragraph above.

Comment: That is not a requirement for an equivalence relation. There are exactly three requirements for an relation to be an equivalence relation (but unfortunately, being called "equivalence" is not among them): reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. By the way, I think your title should say "equivalence" where it says "congruence".

Comment: I see.  It seems as though my book doesn't discuss those requirements for an equivalence relation.  It does discuss symmetric matrices but that's the closest topic to those requirements. My book only covers elementary linear algebra so perhaps that is why.  The title is the same as the exercise out of the book.  It could be a typo.

Comment: Could you cite your book's definition of an equivalence relation?

Comment: I would but I don't believe it gives one.  I've looked through the contents and index and couldn't find anything except for what I've already cited when I posted the question.  I also don't remember ever reading about it even though I'm on the last chapter now.

Comment: It might be they assume knowing such things as prerequisite to reading the book; equivalence relations are pretty general and basic stuff. Please consult Wikipedia or your favourite source of general math knowledge

Comment: I will, thank you.